# How does one create an aliased task in Ada?

Tags: ada, multitasking

Consider the code below. How do I make the task `MainTask` aliasable and so accessible via an `access` type?

```
 private with Ada.Text_IO;
 private with Interfaces.C;
 private with Interfaces.C.Strings;

 procedure Main is
    package Text_IO renames Ada.Text_IO;
    package C renames Interfaces.C;
    package CStrings renames Interfaces.C.Strings;

    function Puts(S : C.Char_Array) return C.Int;
    pragma Import (C, Puts, "puts");

    package WriteListener is
       type Object is task interface;

       procedure WriteDone (This : in Object; Result : C.Int) is abstract;
    end WriteListener;

    task type Writer (Receiver : access WriteListener.Object'Class) is
       entry Write (Str : in String);
    end Writer;


    task body Writer is
       Result : C.Int;
    begin
       loop
          select
             accept Write (Str : in String) do
                Result := Puts(C.To_C(Str));
             end Write;
             Receiver.WriteDone(Result);
          or
             terminate;
          end select;
       end loop;
    end Writer;

    task MainTask is new WriteListener.Object with
      entry WriteDone (Result : C.Int);
    end MainTask;

    task body MainTask is
       MyWriter :  Writer := new Writer (Receiver => MainTask'Access);
       R : C.Int;
    begin
       R := Puts(C.To_C("Starting asynchronous write"));

       MyWriter.Write("Hello, world!");

       EventLoop: loop
          declare
             TimeToExit : Boolean := False;
          begin

             accept WriteDone (Result : C.Int) do
                R := Puts(C.To_C("Asynchronous write completed"));
                TimeToExit := True;
             end WriteDone;

             exit EventLoop when TimeToExit;
          end;
       end loop EventLoop;
    end MainTask;
 begin
    null;
 end Main;
```

Comment: [`Prod_Cons`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.ada/fSyLRIfvIUU/BLqrpZRqq2QJ) may offer some insight.

Comment: `private with` doesn't make sense for a procedure.

Comment: You are only actually using one of the three packages you `with`.

Answer (score 2):

One hacky workaround is to declare a task type like follows. There's also probably a way to construct the writer task without heap allocation but I don't know the syntax for that.

```
private with Ada.Text_IO;
private with Interfaces.C;
private with Interfaces.C.Strings;

procedure Main is
   package Text_IO renames Ada.Text_IO;
   package C renames Interfaces.C;
   package CStrings renames Interfaces.C.Strings;

   function Puts(S : C.Char_Array) return C.Int;
   pragma Import (C, Puts, "puts");

   package WriteListener is
      type Object is task interface;
      procedure WriteDone (This : in Object; Result : C.Int) is abstract;
   end WriteListener;

   task type Writer (Receiver : not null access WriteListener.Object'Class) is
      entry Write (Str : in String);
   end Writer;

   task body Writer is
      Result : C.Int;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept Write (Str : in String) do
               Result := Puts(C.To_C(Str));
            end Write;
            Receiver.WriteDone(Result);
         or
            terminate;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Writer;

   task type MainTask is new WriteListener.Object with
     entry WriteDone (Result : C.Int);
   end MainTask;

   MyMainTask : aliased MainTask;

   task body MainTask is
      MyWriter : not null access Writer := new Writer (Receiver => MyMainTask'Access);
      R : C.Int;
   begin
      R := Puts(C.To_C("Starting asynchronous write"));

      MyWriter.Write("Hello, world!");

      EventLoop: loop
          declare
             TimeToExit : Boolean := False;
          begin

             accept WriteDone (Result : C.Int) do
                R := Puts(C.To_C("Asynchronous write completed"));
                TimeToExit := True;
             end WriteDone;

             exit EventLoop when TimeToExit;
          end;
      end loop EventLoop;
   end MainTask;
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your `Main_Task` object an aliased object of type `Main_Task_Type`.

Also; don't waste heap allocation on your `Writer` task.

And one more thing; remember to check the result from `Puts` every time you call it.

Comment: `MainTask` is of an anonymous type, so there is no way to refer to it in the type system, like `Receiver` needs to do. I think. (Maybe just like the former object cannot be renamed, cf. LRM 8.5(5)).

Comment: That is trivial to change.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the pattern in this way might be felt by some to torture the language a bit. But, anyway, if an an aliased task unit of the kind *single_task_declaration* is desired, there is none, since an aliasing declaration requires a type name, whereas a single task declaration is  of an anonymous type. The solutions presented have thus used a type and declared `SomeMainTask` to be of that type, and aliased. This achieves `'Access`.

Addressing the problem to be solved more generally, if there is just one task `MainTask`, then all callers (finitely many) can refer to it simply by it's name, circumventing the need for pointing to it. The key is to **with** a package containing this single task wherever it is needed.

Another option to consider is tasks referring to each other by ID; every task can provide its ID to some registry, say.

But if a singleton task of some named type is required for other reasons, then it can be done. One way is to wrap the single task and use **requeue** in all wrapping objects. But, OTOH, if these tasks should implement a synchronized interface, they need to be tasks, too, so nothing much might be gained.

The following outline reuses the original program for a demonstration of how one might proceed, albeit emphasizing only the singleton-ness, not so much the structure of communication and control. Alternatives more likely to produce an Ada-like solution would need rethinking the problem in terms of Ada's message passing facilities.

```
package Task_Singleton is
   type TaskWrapper is synchronized new WriteListener.Object with private;
private
   task type TaskWrapper is new WriteListener.Object with
      entry WriteDone (Result : C.Int);
   end TaskWrapper;
   task MainTask is new WriteListener.Object with
      entry WriteDone (Result : C.Int);
   end MainTask;
end Task_Singleton;

package body Task_Singleton is

   task body MainTask is
      R : C.Int;
   begin

   EventLoop: loop
         declare
            TimeToExit : Boolean := False;
         begin

            accept WriteDone (Result : C.Int) do
               R := Puts(C.To_C("Asynchronous write completed"));
               TimeToExit := True;
            end WriteDone;

            exit EventLoop when TimeToExit;
         end;
      end loop EventLoop;
   end MainTask;

   MainWrapper: aliased TaskWrapper;

   task body TaskWrapper is
      MyWriter :  Writer (Receiver => MainWrapper'Access);
      R : C.Int;
   begin
      R := Puts(C.To_C("Starting asynchronous write"));

      MyWriter.Write("Hello, world!");
      loop
         select
            accept WriteDone (Result : C.Int) do
               requeue MainTask.WriteDone;
            end WriteDone;
          or
            terminate;
         end select;
      end loop;

   end Taskwrapper;
end Task_Singleton;
```